# C# array of threads

Tags: c#, threadpool

So I am creating a class called `Operator` this class contains a fixed amount of different threads.

I want a method in my Operator that starts all of my threads by looping through the array.

I am new to C# and cannot seem to make this work, I am originally a java programmer and in java I would have been able to do it like this:

```
    Private Thread[] threadArray;
    Public someConstructor(){
   Thread t1 = new Thread();
   Thread t2 = new Thread();
this.threadArray = new Thread[t1, t2]


} 
public void runThreads(){

    for (Thread t : threadArray) {
        t.start();
    }
}
```

However, in C# I am unable to do this here is my code example:

```
   private Thread tHenvendelser;
    private Thread[] threadArray;
    /// <summary>
    /// Operator constuctor.
    /// </summary>
    /// 
    public Operator() { )
    this.tHenvendelser = new Thread()
    this.threadArray = new Thread[tHenvendelser];
    }
```

Comment: Which version of .net you are using? If 4.0 then probably you can reply on TPL rather than trying to manage yours?

Comment: On a side note, if you aren't aware of it, you should certainly look into Tasks: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you are creating an array with "tHenvendelser" number of items.

```
this.threadArray = new Thread[tHenvendelser];
```

I suspect (hard to say) you really want:

```
this.threadArray = new Thread[1];
this.threadArray[0] = tHenvendelser;
```

Or the shorthand:

```
this.threadArray = new Thread[] { tHenvendelser };
```

... while we are at it, the C# syntax for the `foreach` would be:

```
public void runThreads()
{
  foreach(Thread t in threadArray) {
    t.start();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you the short hand did the job for me! :)

Comment: That said, yes, the Task Parallel Library would probably be the way to go for what you are aiming at (as @GeorgeJohnston commented)